# What is the small tray called when paying for something in person?

Tags: translation, meaning, words, loanwords

When I pay for something I don't hand the money over directly. I put it in a small tray.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Most "officially", it is called [「カルトン」](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%AB%E3%83%AB%E3%83%88%E3%83%B3).

As it says in the Wiki article above, it is also called  「キャッシュトレイ」、「コイントレイ」、「釣{つ}り銭{せん}トレイ」, etc.

For those interested, I just found an article on this subject in the [Japan Times](http://www.japantimes.co.jp/news/2015/05/23/reference/change-trays/#.WIky9zHavVI).

Comment: I read that JapanTimes article a while ago and was gonna link it when I saw the question in "Hot Network Questions"